# communicate javascript with php script

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am trying to send data from Javascript to a php script. I am new to PHP,javascript and JSON etc. I am tryin to use jQuery Upvote plugin. I am reading the documentation from readme.md [here](https://github.com/janosgyerik/jquery-upvote#jquery-upvote---a-voting-plugin). However, I find it too vague for my understanding.

I have added the following code in HTML body. The plugin is working fine in front-end.

```
<div id="topic" class="upvote">
    <a class="upvote"></a>
    <span class="count">0</span>
    <a class="downvote"></a>
    <a class="star"></a>
</div>
<div id="output"> </div>
<script language="javascript">
var callback = function(data) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/vote',
        type: 'post',
        data: { id: data.id, up: data.upvoted, down: data.downvoted, star: data.starred }
    });
};
$('#topic').upvote({id: 123, callback: callback});
</script>
```

Can someone please tell how should I write the php counterpart so as to get the information about change of state of plugin? I think it is related to json maybe but I am stuck here..

**EDIT:** As per the suggestion, I have modified a bit of code and wrote PHP script. 
In above code I have changed URL to my PHP script `url: 'voter.php'`.

This is the PHP code (in brief) :

```
<?php require_once('Connections/conn.php'); ?>
mysql_select_db($database_conn, $conn);
if ($_POST['up']!=0){
$query_categories = "UPDATE user SET score=1 WHERE u_id =5";
$categories = mysql_query($query_categories, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
}
else if ($_POST['down']!=0) {
    $query_categories = "UPDATE user SET score=-1 WHERE u_id =5";
$categories = mysql_query($query_categories, $conn) or die(mysql_error());

}
```

The database connection is working fine, but still the database values are not updated by above code..

Comment: PHP takes in post data. Using the post data, insert/update the relevant record into a database (probably MySQL)

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Comment: how exactly to accept this data? Can you please provide me with an example? I am using MySQL database and I can insert data once I get it into a php variable. I amconfused about how to accept the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script sends AJAX Post request to the php script. You can access those post variables like this, using `$_POST[]` array:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$up = $_POST['up'];
$down = $_POST['down'];
$star = $_POST['star'];
```

Then you can populate the mysql table, etc.

Comment: Okay, I'll try it. Do I need to add anything to callback function? Also, if my php script name is `voter.php`, will the URL `url:'voter.php'` suffice if the php script is in same directory?

Comment: Yes, that's right, you don't need to add anything to the callback, just update your php script. The url is correct.